# how to create a while do done script that has an exit and continue option?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to figure out how to create a while-do-done script in bash that will allow me to select options 1-4 and if I do use 1-4 will allow me to make another selection of pressing 'n' to exit or any key to continue. Thank you for any input, I greatly appreciate it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#while-do-done
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

#options 1-4 have options, option 5-x is else command
echo "Type one of the following:"
echo "1 - whoami"
echo "2 - df"
echo "3 - date"
echo "4 - cal"
echo -n "select option:"

read option

while [ $option == "1" ]
 whoami

echo "Enter another command?"

echo "Press 'n' to exit. Any key to continue"

if [ $option == "n" ]
 then exit
fi

while [ $option == "2" ]
 df

while [ $option == "3" ]
 date

while [ $option == "4" ]
 cal

while [ $option == * ]
 printf "${RED} You made an invalid selection. Exiting.${NC}"

exit 0
```

Comment: Please use shellcheck.net to fix the more obvious errors first.

Comment: Spaces are important to the shell. The `[` and `]` on those `if` and `while` lines aren't syntactic parentheses. `[` is an actual command. So the `[` and `]` need spaces around them.

Comment: @ chepner what exactly do you mean by "obvious errors" ?

@ Etan so "if [$option = n]" would need to be "if [ $option = n ]"

Comment: @Kris If you put the code into shellcheck.net, as Chepner suggested, it would be obvious to you what Chepner meant by "obvious errors."

Comment: While is a loop; you don't want to loop 4 times. You want one loop that keeps going infinitely. Inside the loop, you check for input values and act on them, or use `break` to get out of it.

Comment: I think you can use the functions in script.

Comment: Check [`man bash`](http://man.cx/bash), particularly, this section: `select name [ in word ] ; do list ; done`. Also, take a note about `PS3` prompt mentioned.

Comment: Kris, it looks to me as if you're trying to use `while` as if it were `case`. It might be useful for you to write out the functionality you want in "meta-code" -- that is, in plain language that can be used to describe better what you are really trying to do.  You mention "while-do-done", yet you include no "do" or "done" in your script.  [What are you REALLY trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

showmenu() {
  echo "Type one of the following:"
  echo " 1 - whoami"
  echo " 2 - df"
  echo " 3 - date"
  echo " 4 - cal"
}

# Your loop starts here.
while true; do

  showmenu    # This calls the function above.

  read -p "Enter selection: " option

  case "$option" in
    1) whoami ;;
    2) df ;;
    3) date ;;
    4) cal ;;
    *)
      echo "${RED}Invalid selection. Exiting.${NC}"
      break    # Quit the loop, resuming execution after "done"
      ;;
  esac

  read -p "Enter another command (y/n)?" cont

  case "$cont" in
    N*|n*) break ;;    # Quit the loop, resuming execution after "done"
    *) continue ;;     # Restart the loop. Not strictly necessary here,
                       # since there's nothing left to skip before "done".
  esac

done

echo "I quit."
```

Most of this script does not require bash, by the way; you could run it with `/bin/sh` on most systems.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish! I was unsure of how to go about creating a loop. I have seen plenty of examples but nothing really 'clicked' to me. I used to do C++ and I honestly believe that was easier for me than this. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: The C++ equivalent to a bash "case" statement would be a "switch" statement. SO many languages these days are really just different vocabulary for exactly the same grammar.  Note that where the loop condition in my answer says `true` (after "while"), you can put any condition that you'd use for an `if` statement.  For example, `while [ $count -lt $limit ]; do`...  You can `man test` in a shell for a sample of the tests available.